# In React Native calendar picker, I want to disable some dates by giving a function

Tags: react-native, datepicker, calendar

I have been working on a calendar topic (react-native-calendar-picker). If this does not work can you suggest me with a date picker dependency which has, range availability, disable dates and if possible to disable weekends. I am using moment.

My code:

```
import CalendarPicker from 'react-native-calendar-picker';
import moment from 'moment';
<CalendarPicker
          startFromMonday={true}
          allowRangeSelection={true}
          minDate={minDate}
          maxDate={maxDate}
          //disabledDates={[new Date('13/02/2021'), new Date('14/02/2021'), new Date('14/02/2021')]} tried so many forms too
          disabledDates={  Date(2021,2,13)}
          width={250}
          height={250}
          maxRangeDuration={10}
          todayBackgroundColor="#f2e6ff"
          selectedDayColor="#7300e6"
          selectedDayTextColor="#FFFFFF"
          onDateChange={this.onDateChange}
        />
```

Comment: I personally used `react-native-calendars` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-calendars) and it worked really nice and the documentation is well written (it also is quite customisable). Maybe this is helpful to you

Comment: @dianaqqq thank you very much i got all the features wanted in this .could u mind how to write a function to disable the period of day say from 12-02-2021 to 14-03-2021.

Comment: I checked the issues from the library you've mentioned and I think the problem is that disabled dates you've given are not the right format. They should be timestamp, like this `2021-02-12T10:01:13+02:00`, which can be obtained like this `moment('2021-02-12').format()`  (https://github.com/stephy/CalendarPicker/issues/263)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<CalendarPicker
    ...
    disabledDates={date => {
          let startDate = {...this.state.selectedStartDate}
          let endDate ={...this.state.selectedEndDate}
          if(date.isBetween(startDate, endDate)){
                 return true
          } else {
                return false
          }
    }}
    // or use it as an array
```

I believe you can also pass a function but I haven't tried that yet.

Comment: I was looking for some idea about resetting date selections or changing it. But they haven't provided any method to clear date values.

Answer (score 0):

use react-date-range this package to add date picker in my react website front-end..
i think you can also do like in react-native.. if you needed, you can get help from this code
i get it from this https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-date-range

i code like below to disable multiple dates in select calender and i use harcoded data set

```
//date data set
const reservedDates = [
 2024/01/27','2024/01/28','2024/02/04','2024/02/05','2024/01/30','2024/02/07'
];
const [selectionRange,setSelectRange] = useState({
   startDate: new Date(),
   endDate: new Date(),
   key: "selection",
});
        
const [disabledDatesArr, setDisabledDatesArr] = useState([]);

function formatDate(string){
   var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric'};
   return new Date(string).toLocaleDateString([],options);
}
          
useEffect(() => {
   let updated = []
   reservedDates.map((date) => {
       let d = new Date(date);
       let dates = [d.getFullYear(),d.getMonth()+1,d.getDate()];
       updated.push(new Date(dates))
   });
   setDisabledDatesArr(updated);
}, []);
const handleSelect = (range) =>{
    setSelectRange({...selectionRange, 
                    startDate: range.selection.startDate, 
                    endDate: range.selection.endDate}
    );
}
return(
  <DateRangePicker
    rangeColors={["#FF7F50"]}
    disabledDates={[...disabledDatesArr]}
    ranges={[selectionRange]}
    onChange={handleSelect}
  />
)
```